# Change class component to functional component with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert a class component to functional component but i keep getting problem, I think im doing it wrongly

Class Component:

```
class CountC extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.refreshCart();
      }

 render(){
        const { cart } = this.props;

        return (
           <p> {`${cart !== null ? cart.order_items.length : 0}`}</p>
);
}};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {

      cart: state.cart.shoppingCart,
    };
  };


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        refreshCart: () => dispatch(fetchCart()),

    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CountC);
```

This is what i try to do as my Functional Component (Please note I dont understand function component just yet)

```
function CountC(props) {
  const [refreshCart, setRefreshCart] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setRefreshCart(true);
    console.log("component mounted!");
  }, []);

return ( <p> {`${cart !== null ? cart.order_items.length : 0}`}</p> );

 const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
    
          cart: state.cart.shoppingCart,
        };
      };
    
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            refreshCart: () => dispatch(fetchCart()),
    
        }
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CountC);
```

Its not giving me the desired output, I have tried tweaking it, still!,

Comment: Make sure `mapStateToProps ` and `mapDispatchToProps ` are outside of the Functional Component

Comment: also you could use hooks to replace them: `useSelector` and `useDispatch`

Comment: `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` should be outside the component, not sure if you really closed your `CountC` component before it. In your return, `cart` should be `props.cart` and in your `useEffect` you should call `props.refreshCart()`

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I took `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`  outside the component..... In my useEffect, you I should replace setRefreshCart with `props.refreshCart()` or just add `props.refreshCart()` to it?

Comment: Replace `setRefreshCart` with `props.refreshCart()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, please.

```
 const CountC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart.shoppingCart);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(refreshCart());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return <p> {`${cart !== null ? cart.order_items.length : 0}`}</p>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps should be outside the component and while using functional components you should use props.cart and props.refreshCart() instead of this.props.cart and this.props.refreshCart()

```
    function CountC(props) {
          
          useEffect(() => {
            props.refreshCart(true);
            console.log("component mounted!");
          }, []);
        
        return ( <p> {`${props.cart !== null ? props.cart.order_items.length : 0}`}</p> );
        
      }
        
        const mapStateToProps = state => {
           return {
              cart: state.cart.shoppingCart,
                };
        };
            
            
        const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
           return {
              refreshCart: () => dispatch(fetchCart()),
                  }
        }
            
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CountC);
```

And you can also use useSelector and useDispatch hooks instead of using mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

```
    import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'


    function CountC(props) {

          const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart.shoppingCart)
         
          const dispatch= useDispatch()

          useEffect(() => {
            dispatch.refreshCart(true);
            console.log("component mounted!");
          }, [dispatch]);

        return ( <p> {`${props.cart !== null ? props.cart.order_items.length : 0}`}</p> );
      }

  export default CountC;
```

Comment: I keep getting `TypeError: dispatch.refreshCart is not a function. (In 'dispatch.refreshCart(true)', 'dispatch.refreshCart' is undefined)`